# Compare main table with all records from another table to derive the column value of the main table

Tags: sql, performance, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

I have two tables `tb1` & `main_tbl` with sample dataset as shown below and I'm trying to derive the value for the column `COL_VAL` for the main table. So I have created the query for getting the expected value. However I'm looking for the possibility to simply the number of code lines and achieve the same result

**`main_tbl Table:`**

```
col1        col2        col3         COL_VAL
123          Hi          568           ??
```

**`tbl Table:`**

```
col1        col2        col3        col4        col5
123          LN           Y           IP         2021-02-01
123          LN           N           NON-IP     2021-02-01
123          MOB          Y           AP         2021-02-01
123          MOB          N           NON-AP     2021-02-01
```

**`Main Query:`**

```
SELECT
d.COL1,
d.COL2,
d.COL3,
CAST(COALESCE(FRT_QRY.COL4,SND_QRY.COL4,FIF_QRY.COL4,TRD_QRY.COL4) AS STRING)  AS COL_VAL
FROM 
 (
 SELECT * FROM db.main_tbl)d
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3 ORDER BY col5 desc) as Rnk
        FROM ( select  *  from    db.tb1  where   col2 IN ('LN') and col3 = 'Y') b
    ) a where a.Rnk =1 
) SND_QRY
on d.col1=SND_QRY.col1
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3 ORDER BY col5 desc) as Rnk
        FROM ( select  *  from    db.tb1  where   col2 IN ('LN') and col3 = 'N') b
    ) a where a.Rnk =1 
) TRD_QRY
on d.col1=TRD_QRY.col1
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3 ORDER BY col5 desc) as Rnk
        FROM ( select  *  from    db.tb1  where   col2 IN ('MOB') and col3 = 'Y') b
    ) a where a.Rnk =1 
) FRT_QRY
on d.col1=FRT_QRY.col1
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3 ORDER BY col5 desc) as Rnk
        FROM ( select  *  from    db.tb1  where   col2 IN ('MOB') and col3 = 'N') b
    ) a where a.Rnk =1 
) FIF_QRY
on d.col1=FIF_QRY.col1
```

**`Expected Output - main_tbl Table:`**

```
col1        col2        col3         COL_VAL
123          Hi          568           AP
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with something, I noticed that all your subqueries contain different filters applied to the same columns and those columns are in partition by clause. This means that filters do not affect row_number and you can calculate row_number once without filters and use filters as join conditions or filter in join subqueries:

```
WITH RANKED AS (
SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT b.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3 ORDER BY col5 desc) as Rnk
        FROM db.tb1 b
    ) a where a.Rnk =1 
)

SELECT
d.COL1,
d.COL2,
d.COL3,
CAST(COALESCE(FRT_QRY.COL4,SND_QRY.COL4,FIF_QRY.COL4,TRD_QRY.COL4) AS STRING)  AS COL_VAL
FROM 
 (
 SELECT * FROM db.main_tbl)d
LEFT JOIN RANKED SND_QRY on d.col1=SND_QRY.col1 AND SND_QRY.col2 IN ('LN')  AND SND_QRY.col3 = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN RANKED TRD_QRY on d.col1=TRD_QRY.col1 AND TRD_QRY.col2 IN ('LN')  AND TRD_QRY.col3 = 'N'
LEFT JOIN RANKED FRT_QRY on d.col1=FRT_QRY.col1 AND FRT_QRY.col2 IN ('MOB') AND FRT_QRY.col3 = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN RANKED FIF_QRY on d.col1=FIF_QRY.col1 AND FIF_QRY.col2 IN ('MOB') AND FIF_QRY.col3 = 'N'
```

Also if you are lucky and have Hive version with CTE materialization feature, use this setting:

```
set hive.optimize.cte.materialize.threshold=2;--HIVE-11752
```

RANKED CTE will be calculated only one time and the same result used in all joins.

Also you can try to eliminate many joins with the same table. Calculate all fields in single query using CASE expressions + aggregation and join only one time. Aggregation works faster than joins:

```
WITH RANKED AS (
SELECT col1,
       --aggregate all in single row per col1 
       max(case when col2 IN ('LN') AND col3 = 'Y' then COL4 else null end) as SND_COL4,
       max(case when col2 IN ('LN') AND col3 = 'N' then COL4 else null end) as TRD_COL4,
       max(case when col2 IN ('MOB') AND col3 = 'Y' then COL4 else null end) as FRT_COL4,
       max(case when col2 IN ('MOB') AND col3 = 'N' then COL4 else null end) as FIF_COL4   
FROM 
    ( SELECT b.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3 ORDER BY col5 desc) as Rnk
        FROM db.tb1 b
       WHERE (col2 IN ('LN') AND col3 = 'Y') 
          or (col2 IN ('LN') AND col3 = 'N') 
          or (col2 IN ('MOB') AND col3 = 'Y')
          or (col2 IN ('MOB') AND col3 = 'N')
    ) a where a.Rnk =1 
          
GROUP BY col1
)

SELECT
d.COL1,
d.COL2,
d.COL3,
CAST(COALESCE(R.FRT_COL4,R.SND_COL4,R.FIF_COL4, R.TRD_COL4) AS STRING)  AS COL_VAL
FROM 
 (
 SELECT * FROM db.main_tbl)d
LEFT JOIN RANKED R d.col1=R.col1
```